# MUI Autocomplete filterOptions disabled search

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**The problem**, when filtering a specific value from my Autocomplete, it indeed filters it but also the search capability no longer works on the autocomplete.

Here is the code:

```
<Autocomplete
          fullWidth
          // needed to remove mui error related to groupBy
          options={sortedDimensionTypes}
          // filter out the empty option
          filterOptions={(options) => options.filter((option) => option.id !== "-1")}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.data?.label}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option?.id === value?.id}
          groupBy={(option) => optionsGroupLabel(option.data.type)}
          size="small"
          onChange={(_, newValue, reason) => {
            switch (reason) {
              case "clear":
                setFilters((prevFilters) => {
                  const newFilters = prevFilters.slice();
                  newFilters.splice(currentIndex, 1, getBaseAttributionFilter());
                  return newFilters;
                });
                handleSelectOption(getBaseMetadataOption());
                break;
              case "selectOption":
                setFilters((prevFilters) => {
                  const newFilters = prevFilters.slice();
                  const fltr = filterBase(newValue as MetadataOption);
                  newFilters.splice(currentIndex, 1, fltr);
                  return newFilters;
                });
                handleSelectOption(newValue as MetadataOption);
                break;
            }
          }}
          openOnFocus
          // disable clearable when no option selected.
          disableClearable={selectedType.id === "-1"}
          renderInput={(params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
            <TextField {...params} label={attributionText.DIMENSION_TYPE} variant="outlined" margin="dense" />
          )}
          value={selectedType}
        />
```

**Expected behavior**: it would simply filter out the option without an `id` (where the id equals -1) and allow searching on the rest.
**Actual Behavior**: typing a search does nothing.

Here is a simple recreation with a basic example from the MUI examples.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yzmpeh?file=demo.tsx

Comment: Can you create sandbox for your problem?

Comment: added to my question (slightly different but it's the same issue)